# Redirecting from base app to another app in same Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I am having a issue in redirecting from one application deployed in tomcat to another deployed in same tomcat.
I have a up and running project which works with apache webserver at front and then we are using apache tomcat. Mod_JK is being used there. 
I am able to access it using www.example.com. which access the example1 in tomcat webapps.

Now we are introducing a new product example2. The new product is completely different in functionality so I am planning to create a different war and deploy in tomcat. The entry point for both the product needs to be same page.From where user can choose product and after login will be redirected to the respective product.
I am not able to find a way to redirect to the new products pages from the old product page.

My issue is www.example.com points to https://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/example1
now if i want to redirect it to example2. how should I change
 xx.xx.xx.xx:80/example1 to  https://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/example2 when I am using the domain name which points to the first url.
Any help

Comment: Please send your worker.properties and JkMount/uriworkermap.properties mappings